# Magento 2 change product description using API on every 5 seconds

Tags: magento2, product, api, cron

I am working on Magento2, and I've to change my product description on every five minutes using the third-party API.
Then I've 1laksh product in my Magento, so which approach is better to change the product description.

**Approach1:**

Create a new Magento Cron & get the product collection with some limit value(10), once the description getting updated. I'll be going to maintain a new field api_updated_time.

so it'll update the descriptions for the first 10 product and update the new field value.

In the second time Cron was running I am checking the time difference between the api_updated_time and Cron running time, based on that I am updating the next ten products.

The above is the right approach or else is there has any better method to accomplish the logic.

Kindly check and share your thoughts.

Comment: 1laksh product means ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going right, you can improve it as:

Execute cron at each minute and set **limit value()** as per the number of products in collection so that in each cycle of 5 minute, all the products description gets updated.

Also note the time difference between job

> executed_at

and

> finished_at

If it is taking more than 60 seconds for each execution, try increasing **limit value()** and test.

Comment: Do you have any other approach for this process ?

Comment: You want to change description on every 5 seconds or minutes ?

Comment: Every 5 Minutes

Comment: Have you tried with mentioned approach.. what are the outcomes ?

Comment: No, I need one more approach, if it's better than the current I'll proceed with that or else i will continue my current approach